# Run an asynchronous call of Cheerios with a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, cheerio

I have a promise call that is supposed to do the following:

1) Get a link from completedLinks

2) Use cheerio to load the html into the $, like jQuery.

3) get the title, and other details from the page

4) save those details to the object `siteObj`

JS:

```
completedLinks = ["http://www.example.com/1","http://www.example.com/2","http://www.example.com/3"...]

   function fetchSiteDetails(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(promise, link) {
        console.log(link);
        var siteObj = {};

        var $ = cheerio.load(link);
        var titles = $("title").text().trim();  
        var html = $("#content").html().trim();
        var mainContent = $(".left-side").html().trim();
        var allLinks = $('a');

        siteObj.title = titles;
        siteObj.html = html;
        siteObj.mainContent = mainContent;
        siteObj.subPages = [];

       allLinks.each(function(i, elem) {
         siteObj.subPages.push($(this).attr('href'));
       });

        return promise;
      }, Promise.resolve());
    }

    fetchSiteDetails(completedLinks).then(function() {
        console.log('all done');
    });
```

Right now it is not completing each task before it starts the next, and finishes before it's done anything.

Comment: you're returning the one resolved promise in each iteration of the reduce function - which part of the reduce code is at all asynchronous, I can't tell from the code ... what is `completedLinks` an array of?

Answer (score 1):

As I can't see what is asynchronous in your code, here's a generic pattern to run asynchronous operations in series using promises and array.reduce

```
return arr.reduce(function(promise, link) {
    return promise.then(function(resultOfPreviousPromise) {
        // your code goes here
        // return a promise that resolves when the asynchronous function completes
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

What will interest you is the bit where that says "your code goes here" - which is where you should put your code. The return value needs to be a promise that is resolved when the asynchronous operation completes